# Best practices for storing maven artifacts in nexus

Tags: maven, gradle, build, version, versioning

In my company we have teams working on services which are built using maven pom's and gradle build scripts. The problem I have is that when the team's build their web applications, the jar files that get's created by one team member needs to be available for other team members in their pom files.

What we were thinking was to have a local nexus repo and then push the built jar files to nexus so that when any other team member builds they also can refer the same jar file.

However this could lead to versioning problems as two team members could be generating the same jar file if they change different files in the same project.

What I would like to know is are their any best practices in doing these types of builds and versioning.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different opinions and strategies on how to manage this process.  Some aspects are relatively common, however.

I'd say there are two key elements:
* Proper use of version definitions and references
* Automated builds and nexus deployments

If you have work ongoing for a specific artifact, for a specific release, then those changes should all go into a specific numbered version of the artifact.  While work is ongoing, that version should end with "-SNAPSHOT".  When the work for a release is completed, that version number should remove the '-SNAPSHOT".  You also likely want to have separate repositories in the Nexus server for "snapshot" and "release" artifacts.

Concerning pushing artifacts to Nexus, this should always be done through automation.  Manually pushing artifacts should be very rare.  When a regular build is done for ongoing work, that should automatically deploy the "-SNAPSHOT" artifact to the snapshot repo.  When your build automation is running a "release" build, those artifacts will deploy the release artifact to the release repo.

There are many other options and details you'll want to examine.  Only implement features in this process that provide clear value in your situation.  It's very easy to set up a process that is more complicated than you need.

Comment: Thanks David, while a developer is developing we will be using local gradle script that will build to a nexus repo. So if we have '-SNAPSHOT-' repo, to identify the individual developer who might be building the same jar would it be good to add the developer name to that jar. like '-SNAPSHOT-JAMES_E-...' ?

Comment: No, I see no value in that. Source control has identities for changes, but the team constructs binary artifacts collaboratively.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks David. Will discuss with the team and come up with a process around what you mentioned.